# Access 2016 VBA How to skip if Applyfilter is null

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office, isnull

I am trying to get this code to skip to another line if the value is null.  Here is a SHORTENED version of the script.

```
For Counter =1 to 10
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "Name like '" & "*" & DoctorsName & "*" & "'"
DoCmd.OutputTo acSendReport, "", acFormatPDF, "C:Directory\Title.pdf"
DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
Next Counter
```

If the filter it is trying to apply is not in the report, I want it to go to the DoCmd.ShowAllRecords line.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For Counter =1 to 10 
     If Dcount("*",[add here the recordsource],"Name like '" & "*" & DoctorsName & "*" & "'" ) > 0 THEN 
        DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "Name like '" & "*" & DoctorsName & "*" & "'"  
        DoCmd.OutputTo acSendReport, "", acFormatPDF, "C:Directory\Title.pdf" 
     End If
     DoCmd.ShowAllRecords 
Next Counter
```